# How can I tell if Cisco switch is running PVST or PVST+?

Tags: cisco, switch

On a Cisco 6503 switch, if I run "show spanning-tree summary", it says, "Switch is in pvst mode".

How do I know if this is PVST or PVST+? Would it have specifically said PVST+? Or does it depend on the version of the switch, where PVST could actually mean PVST+?

Answer (score 1):

Cisco uses PVST for ISL trunks and PVST+ for 802.11q trunks. They operate transparently with each other.

Answer (score 1):

What I bet you're really asking is "is my switch running rapid spanning-tree".  Is that right?

```
Cat1(config)#spanning-tree mode pvst                                            
Cat1(config)#do show spann vlan 211 | inc protocol                              
  Spanning tree enabled protocol ieee                                           

Cat1(config)#spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst                     
Cat1(config)#do show spann vlan 211 | inc protocol                              
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp
```

With mode 'pvst', the switch uses Per-VLAN Spanning-Tree (PVST).  Each VLAN runs its own instance of STP using the original 802.1d rules (non-rapid).

With mode 'rapid-pvst', the switch also uses Per-VLAN Spanning-Tree (PVST).  Each VLAN runs its own instance of STP using the updated Rapid STP rules (802.1w).

The other mode is 'mst', which runs a configured number of spanning-tree instances for a set of VLANs (802.1s).  It also uses Rapid STP rules (802.1w).

PVST vs PVST+ has to do with 802.1q support only.